# build-in.o creation in many driver folders

Tags: build, linux-kernel, makefile

I was building a kernel with my custom drivers . after a successful build i found many build-in.o files.Can anybody elaborate how these end up here. I can only suspect these are related to higher level makefiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

built-in.o files are the compiled product of each directory target of the kernel that is not built as a module.

See Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt

> > Each subdirectory has a kbuild Makefile which carries out the commands passed down from above. The kbuild Makefile uses information
> >     from the .config file to construct various file lists used by kbuild
> >     to build any built-in or modular targets.
> >
> > --- 3.1 Goal definitions
>
> ```
>     Goal definitions are the main part (heart) of the kbuild Makefile.
>     These lines define the files to be built, any special compilation
>     options, and any subdirectories to be entered recursively.
>
>     The most simple kbuild makefile contains one line:
>
>     Example:
>             obj-y += foo.o
>
>     This tells kbuild that there is one object in that directory, named
>     foo.o. foo.o will be built from foo.c or foo.S.
>
>     If foo.o shall be built as a module, the variable obj-m is used.
>     Therefore the following pattern is often used:
>
>     Example:
>             obj-$(CONFIG_FOO) += foo.o
>
>     $(CONFIG_FOO) evaluates to either y (for built-in) or m (for module).
>     If CONFIG_FOO is neither y nor m, then the file will not be compiled
>     nor linked.
> ```
>
> --- 3.2 Built-in object goals - obj-y
>
> ```
>     The kbuild Makefile specifies object files for vmlinux
>     in the $(obj-y) lists.  These lists depend on the kernel
>     configuration.
>
>     Kbuild compiles all the $(obj-y) files.  It then calls
>     "$(LD) -r" to merge these files into one built-in.o file.
>     built-in.o is later linked into vmlinux by the parent Makefile.
> ```