# Can't add a directory with code to u-boot project

Tags: linux, makefile, build, u-boot, kbuild

I wanted to call a C function defined in [arm-tf (arm trusted firmware)](https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware) from a u-boot assembly code. That assembly code of u-boot is [arch/arm/lib/gic_64.S](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/v2021.10/source/arch/arm/lib/gic_64.S). The build process for this doesn't work out as I wanted so I ask it here with simple example.

In u-boot build tree, there is the directory `arch/arm/lib`. I added a directory `arch/arm/lib/testd` and put `testf.c` there. testf.c is just printing a string. In `arch/arm/lib/Makefile`, I added

```
libs-y += arch/arm/lib/testd
```

and in `arch/arm/lib/testd/Makefile`, I added

```
obj-y += testf.o
```

When I do `make` in u-boot root directory, I find nothing is made under arch/arm/lib/testd. But if I do `make arch/arm/lib/testd/testf.o`, that file is made. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958065/build-in-o-creation-in-many-driver-folders) but it doesn't help. Actually I guess I should see spl/arch/arm/lib/testd/{built-in.o, testf.o} if it was successful(because I'm building u-boot-spl).
I will be very grateful if anyone could tell me how I should do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, if I add in arch/arm/lib/Makefile only

```
obj-y += testd/
```

Then by doing `make` I see arch/arm/lib/testd/testf.o and spl/arch/arm/lib/testd/{build-in.o,testf.o} generated.
The key part was the `testd/` not `testd`.